# Django GenericRelation inherited from Abstract model in different app fails to generate migration

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I'm trying to create a new model in a new app B, inheriting from an abstract model in app A:

```py
# app_b/models.py
from app_a.models import Foo

class ConcreteModel(Foo):
   pass
```

`Foo` has a GenericRelation to another model of app A:

```py
# app_a/models.py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class Foo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    some_relation = GenericRelation(
        "Bar",
        content_type_field="foo_type",
        object_id_field="foo_id"
    )

class Bar(models.Model):
    # whatever
```

Generation of the initial migration of app B fails with the following SystemCheck errors:

> <function GenericRelation.contribute_to_class..make_generic_foreign_order_accessors at 0x7fa2a6747c80>: (models.E022) <function GenericRelation.contribute_to_class..make_generic_foreign_order_accessors at 0x7fa2a6747c80> contains a lazy reference to app_b.bar, but app 'app_b' doesn't provide model 'bar'.

> app_b.ConcreteModel.some_relation: (fields.E307) The field app_b.ConcreteModel.some_relation was declared with a lazy reference to 'app_b.bar', but app 'app_b' doesn't provide model 'bar'.

Indeed, app_b does not provide Bar, app_a does.

I tried explicitly mentioning app_a in the GenericRelation:

```py
some_relation = GenericRelation(
    "app_a.Bar",
    content_type_field="foo_type",
    object_id_field="foo_id"
)
```

but this does not generate a migration for app_a, nor does it fix the problem.

I'm using Django 2.2. Is there a workaround besides moving ConcreteModel to app_a ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened but the problem disappeared when I used the actual model:

```py
from app_a.models import Bar

some_relation = GenericRelation(
    Bar,
    content_type_field="foo_type",
    object_id_field="foo_id"
)
```

This did not generate any migrations, and worked.